# Placing carousel in the middle of the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I want set my carousel in the middle of the page with a white border attached to it. But I'm unable to do it. I used padding but the border is not adjusting with the carousel. If I reduce a little more the padding then the carousel arrows is not shifting with carousel.
Here is my html file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Carousel Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

<header>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#featured"><h1>Carousel <span class="subhead">Practice</span></h1></a>
      </div><!-- navbar-header -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#featured">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mission">Mission</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#staff">Staff</a></li>
          <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
        </ul>        
      </div><!-- collapse navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- container -->
  </nav>

<div class="container wrapping">
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="featured">

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active"><img src="images/carousel-lifestyle.jpg" alt="Lifestyle Photo"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel-mission.jpg" alt="Mission"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel-vaccinations.jpg" alt="Vaccinations"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel-fish.jpg" alt="Fish"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="images/carousel-exoticanimals.jpg" alt="Exotic Animals"></div>      
    </div><!-- carousel-inner -->

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
    </div>
  </div><!-- featured carousel -->
</header>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700,800|Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700);

/**  Basic Page CSS **/
body{
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: relative;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0;
}

header{
  background-color: #00173f;  
}

.carousel-inner{
 padding: 150px 30px 100px 30px;
 border: 15px solid #fff; border-radius: 5px;
}


/**  Header Navigation **/

header .navbar {
  padding: 30px 0;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

header .navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

header .navbar-default .navbar-nav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 8px;
}

header .navbar-default .navbar-nav a:hover {
  color: #EEC856;
}

header .navbar-default .navbar-nav .active a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #EEC856;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #EEC856;
  text-shadow: none;
}

header .navbar-default .navbar-nav .active a:hover {
  color: #E15D5F;
  background: transparent;
  text-shadow: none;
}

/**  Navbar Brand **/

header .navbar-brand {
  background: url(../images/wisdompetlogo.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 15px 0;
  height: auto;
}

header .navbar-brand h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-left: 105px;
}

header .navbar-brand span.subhead {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: .6em;
  font-weight: 100;
}

/**  Navbar Toggle **/
header .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #279182;
}

header .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: white;
}

@media only screen
and (max-width: 768px) {
  header .navbar-collapse.in {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
  }
}
```

This is one of my images link: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=wisdom+pet+medicine&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=614&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiejtTiqs7PAhWBPo8KHXsbDlwQ_AUIBigB&dpr=1.5#imgrc=uU4osiOZHZGu9M%3A

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if your problem is the border, the positioning, or both.

You have your carousel wrapped in your header. This might prevent it from being positioned in the middle of your page. If you want it to be in its own section I would put it in a container-fluid div class and add styling as desired.